# MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to regex search an integer value in MongoDB. Is this possible?

I'm building a CRUD type interface that allows * for wildcards on the various fields. I'm trying to keep the UI consistent for a few fields that are integers.

Consider:

```
> db.seDemo.insert({ "example" : 1234 });
> db.seDemo.find({ "example" : 1234 });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4bfc2bfea2004adae015220a"), "example" : 1234 }
> db.seDemo.find({ "example" : /^123.*/ });
>
```

As you can see, I insert an object and I'm able to find it by the value. If I try a simple regex, I can't actually find the object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are wanting to do a pattern match on numbers, the way to do it in mongo is use the $where expression and pass in a pattern match.

```
> db.test.find({ $where: "/^123.*/.test(this.example)" })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4bfc3187fec861325f34b132"), "example" : 1234 }
```

Comment: As an unrelated tip, to make this work in PHP, you need to pass in Array('$where' => new MongoCode(/^123.*/.test(this.example)");

Comment: @dalton Just curious here, wouldn't the $regex operator be more efficient than $where?

Comment: Figured that something similar would apply for the Ruby driver as @gary pointed out but no.  This should work like a charm db.test.find( "$where" => "/^123.*/.test(this.example)" )

Comment: nice recipe! note that for me, I got some speedup by removing the .* that follows the 123. Not sure of the scenario for which the .* is useful?

Comment: This would be horribly inefficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: @talentedmrjones, there's mention of this at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1174: "We've thought about this, but don't think allowing regex against non string fields is a great idea.
It will be very slow, and kind of misleading."

Comment: What exactly is *test* in that expression?

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting an error -- **db.customer.find({ $where: "/^123.*/.customer(this.mobile_no)" }) **and its giving me this error : **"errmsg" : "$where is not allowed in this atlas tier"**

Comment: what is test expression ?

Comment: how do you implement this using C# driver?

Comment: what are `.test` and `this` referring to in above example

Answer (score 26):

I am not a big fan of using the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where) query operator because of the way it evaluates the query expression, it doesn't use indexes and the security risk if the query uses user input data.

Starting from MongoDB 4.2 you can use the `$regexMatch|$regexFind|$regexFindAll` available in MongoDB 4.1.9+ and the `$expr` to do this.

```
let regex = /123/;
```

- `$regexMatch` and `$regexFind`

  ```
  db.col.find({
      "$expr": {
          "$regexMatch": {
             "input": {"$toString": "$name"}, 
             "regex": /123/ 
          }
      }
  })
  ```
- `$regexFinAll`

  ```
  db.col.find({
      "$expr": {
          "$gt": [
              { 
                  "$size": { 
                      "$regexFindAll": { 
                          "input": {"$toString": "$name"}, 
                          "regex": "123" 
                      }
                  }
              }, 
              0
          ]
      }
  })
  ```

---

From MongoDB 4.0 you can use the `$toString` operator which is a wrapper around the `$convert` operator to *stringify* integers.

```
db.seDemo.aggregate([ 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$gt": [ 
                { "$indexOfCP": [ 
                    { "$toString": "$example" }, 
                    "123" 
                ] }, 
                -1 
            ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] 
    }}
])
```

If what you want is retrieve all the document which contain a particular substring, starting from release 3.4, you can use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator which allows a [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)itional logic processing.`$indexOfCP`.

```
db.seDemo.aggregate([ 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$gt": [ 
                { "$indexOfCP": [ 
                    { "$toLower": "$example" }, 
                    "123" 
                ] }, 
                -1 
            ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] 
    }}
])
```

which produces:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c668c1c52188b56a235b7"), 
    "example" : 1234 
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c66971c52188b56a235b9"), 
    "example" : 12334 
}
```

---

Prior to MongoDB 3.4, you need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your document and add another computed field which is the string value of your number.

The [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower) and his sibling [`$toUpper`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/) operators respectively convert a string to lowercase and uppercase but they have a little unknown feature which is that they can be used to convert an integer to string.

The [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator returns all those documents that match your pattern using the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator.

```
db.seDemo.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$project": { 
            "stringifyExample": { "$toLower": "$example" }, 
            "example": 1 
        }}, 
        { "$match": { "stringifyExample": /^123.*/ } }
    ]
)
```

which yields:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c668c1c52188b56a235b7"), 
    "example" : 1234,
    "stringifyExample" : "1234"
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("579c66971c52188b56a235b9"), 
    "example" : 12334,
    "stringifyExample" : "12334"
}
```

---

Now, if what you want is retrieve all the document which contain a particular substring, the easier and better way to do this is in the upcoming release of MongoDB (as of this writing) using the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator which allows a [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)itional logic processing.`$indexOfCP`.

```
db.seDemo.aggregate([ 
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$gt": [ 
                { "$indexOfCP": [ 
                    { "$toLower": "$example" }, 
                    "123" 
                ] }, 
                -1 
            ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ] 
    }}
])
```

Comment: thank you, $toLower, saves me adding some if's in my code :)

Comment: @HarpreetSingh, I've updated the answer to include the syntax for version 4.0 and 4.1.9+

Comment: `$regexMatch` doesn't seem to work correctly on 4.1 https://pastebin.com/bnX0cp0C