# Search Substring on a Integer Value

Tags: c#, mongodb, 10gen-csharp-driver

Let's say we have a mongodb collection that has elements containing an int attribute value like: {"MyCollectionAttribute": 12345}

How can I search the string "234" inside the int using `Query<T>.` syntax?

For now it seems to work(as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908100/mongodb-regex-search-on-integer-value)) using raw query like:

```
var query = new QueryDocument("$where", "/234/.test(this.MyCollectionAttribute)");
myCollection.Find(query);
```

Is it preferable to store the values directly as strings instead of integers, since a regex match will be slow? How do you approach theese situations?

**Edit**

Context: a company can have some internal codes that are numbers. In sql server they can be stored as a column of int type in order to have data integrity at database level and then queried from linq to sql with something like:

```
.where(item => item.CompanyCode.ToString().Contains("234"))
```

In this way there is both data integrity at db level and type safety of the query.

I asked the question in order to see how this scenario can be implemented using mongodb.

Comment: It's all about your requirements.  If you're going to be doing this sort of query a lot then it probably makes sense to add a string version of the field, but if you're only occasionally doing it then that would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Does not make much sense what you are asking.

Regular expressions are for search within *strings* and not within *integers*.

If you want to perform a substring search (for whatever reason) then store your numbers
as strings and not as integers - obviously.

Comment: I edited the question and explained the context. Saving numbers as strings is an option but it loses data integrity.