# Python regex on numbers

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

Is it possible to use regex on a number instead of a string?

For example: I have a field in a mongodb that contains the numeric value 1234567 (not stored as a string for sorting purposes etc.). 
Now I want to use regex to find parts of this number, i.e. 456.

On a database-field that contains a string `"1234567"` this is easy: I just pass `re.compile("456")` to my database query. However `re.compile(456)` gets me the following:

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

Any hints on how to accomplish this? Storing my numbers as strings is not really an option, since I would lose lots of other possibilities (like gt/lt, sorting etc.).

**Update:**
Also, I'm passing the regex right into the db-query to filter results, so I cannot pull up an individual field, convert it's content to a string and then use the regex on it.

Comment: Convert that field to string first using `str` and then apply regex on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a number to a string using the built-in `str` function:

```
str(456)
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy ;-) I can't match against a number: TypeError: expected string or buffer. And converting my numeric fields in mongodb is not an option either as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Marking as duplicate: [MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908100/mongodb-regex-search-on-integer-value)

```
db.test.find({ $where: "/^123.*/.test(this.example)" })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4bfc3187fec861325f34b132"), "example" : 1234 }
```

Comment: I'm reluctant to use javascript in my query for performance-reasons. Mongodb allows regex-filtering with the $regex-operator ...any insights on how to use this instead?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work

Comment: You should benchmark and compare against your constraints. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with MongoDB. Depending on your application, you might be able to store these numbers as string-typed values instead of numbers. In Python:

`db.collection.insert({"my_number": "12345678"})`

For phone numbers or zipcodes where arithmetic operations like `$inc` don't make sense, but where you want to use a regex to search your data, this could make sense.

An alternate approach could be to store each number **both** as a string and as a number:

`db.collection.insert({"s": "12345678", "n": 12345678})`