# MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value in nested object

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

[MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2908100/4243555). - my question isn't duplicate.
I'd like to know how search on interger value in NESTED object.
I know that there is almost the same question, but mine is a little bit different.
Assume I have an document  in `mongo` collection like this:

```
var doc = {
    phone: 11111,
    uId: {
       internalId: 123  
    }
};
```

I find out that I can use regex search on integer value in mongodb with '$`where`' condition like in this post [MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2908100/4243555).

So... if I make request in a terminal:

```
db.myCollection.find({$where: "/^21.*/.test(this.uId.internalId)"}) - it works as expected
```

But if  I try to send the same request with mongoose  - I have an exception:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined

In other case, if I try to send something like this:

```
db.myCollection.find({$where: "/^21.*/.test(this.phone)"}) - it also works
```

Could anybody give me idea how search by number field in nested object with regex?

Code example

```
//This function return object wich will be passed to model.find();
//key - it is field vich I will use for search on
//value - I tnink it' clear
function numberFilter(key, value) {
    var where = '$where';
    obj[where] = '/^' + value + '.*/.test(this.' + key + ')';
    console.log('obj', obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Here I get object with parameters for search and pass it to `find()` method

```
var query= numberFilter('uId.internalId', 123); // won't work
var query1= numberFilter('phone', 123); // it will work

return MyModel
    .find(query)
    .then(success)
    .catch(next);

function success(data) {
    res.json(data);
}
```

Comment: I added an answer to the question you linked which will work in your case.

Comment: Your answer works  when pass requests via terminal, but with using mongoose you also will get exception

Comment: How are you running your query with Mongoose? Please add the query to your question.

Comment: @SSDMS: I added query

Comment: @SSDMS: `db.seDemo.find({ 'example': /^123.*/ })` - I didn't see it before. I think I should check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118714/discussion-between-ssdms-and-vlad).