# MongoDB - Find by keyword - different data types

Tags: mongodb

I'm using `MongoDB` as my database engine and trying to execute a `find` query based on a given keyword. If all of the data fields are type of `String`, then I could perform the `find` query like this:

```
test.find({
    $or: [
        {'field1': {'$regex': req.body.keyword} },
        {'field2': {'$regex': req.body.keyword} }
    ]})
    .then(function(records) {
        if(records.length >= 1) {
            return res.json({error: false, message: null, data: records});
        } else {
            return res.json({error: false, message: "No results", data: null});
        }
    });
```

However, I have some fields that has a field type of `Number` and `$reqex` cannot be used with any other types than `String`.

Is it even possible to perform a `find` query on different data types? Any help/ideas/thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that in some documents, _field1_ contains a numeric value? Or are you talking about a different field which is always numeric? In that case, can you explain what kind of data you are trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString.) method to convert the numbers to strings as you pass them to the `$regex` operator.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the more general question first, yes, it's possible to perform a find on different data types, not just strings.  $regex is meant for pattern matching on strings though.

Pattern matching on numbers, which seems to be what you are looking for, is demonstrated in this post:
[MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908100/mongodb-regex-search-on-integer-value)

Here's a specific example that may help... the document is inserted and then it is matched using $where. The result is on the last line:

```
db.B_CooperA.insert({number:51})
db.B_CooperA.find({ $where: "/^51*/.test(this.number)" })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e1e4cfb8400a4eb8032748"), "number" : 51 }
```