# MongoDB $regex for integers

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I am trying to make use of `$regex` in my query parameter

```
name[$regex]="^b"
```

This will return bob, bake, bowen etc starting with `b`

But, when I use regex on columns which are INTEGER like

```
id[$regex]="^1"
```

It doesn't return 1, 11, 12, 13 ... etc even though they exist in the database. So, why does `$regex` fails in integer and what are the alternatives

Comment: Not possible till now here is the [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1174).

Comment: So, is there no possible way apart from $regex to achieve same stuff? @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: Use `$toString`  aggregation if you are using mongodb 4.0 to convert integer to string and then use `$regex` or if you are using mongodb version prior to 4.0 use`$toLower` aggregation. As done here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672272/7510657

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB `$regex` operator can only be used against *string* values. See the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) on this.

As a simple workaround, use the `$where` operator to test the integer:

```
db.example.find({ $where: "/^1/.test(this.id)" })
```

Inside the `$where` string, you can use `this` to reference the current document. So in your case, `this.id` is the `id` field you want.