# How to match number using regexp in mongo faster than where

Tags: regex, mongodb

How to match number using regexp in mongo faster than where

I am using `where` but it is verry slow!

Code:
`"$where": "/.*123.*/.test(this.status)"` 
or
`"$where": "/.*sometext.*/.test(this.status)"`

(I would like to match string too)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query MongoDB with "like"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

Comment: @Valijon no! it is for string, not for numbers

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672272/3710490