# Regex query in spring boot mongoDB on integer

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

My data schema in mongoDB

{

```
 id:type(string),
 itemId:type(int),
 itemName:type(string)
```

}

I want to query on itemId such that if (In my database itemId is (1,2,12 , 13 , 15 27) )

if i search for itemId 1 then it fetch data start from 1 mean fetch data of itemId(1,12,13,15)

if i am not pass itemId then fetch whole data.

Please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Regex Search on Integer Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908100/mongodb-regex-search-on-integer-value)

Comment: No, I need this query on spring frame work .It's for mongo console.

Comment: You need to write this query on spring framework

Comment: Start by formulating and testing the query in mongo shell. Then move on to figuring out how to express it in your language/framework.

Comment: is there any function like "findByItemName" or any other in spring frameWork not query annotation because i solve all query like this type of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem i store all itemId in string and build like query.

Thanks for support